# “[NOUN] in veins” eg. “MUSICIAN in veins” meaning

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, idioms, metaphors, figurative-language

Phrase: ***"Musician in veins"***

Is it correct? Can it be misinterpreted? Is it easily understandable for english speaking person? **How do YOU understand it?**

Comment: It is more usually heard as "I have **music** in my veins/blood"

Comment: Where did it come from?

Comment: It is not understandable. We can guess what it means as others have pointed out, but we might guess wrong. If you wrote the phrase, you need to tell us what you want it to mean. If someone else wrote it, then we need to know where you found it and in what context.

Comment: I intentionally gave minimum information out of context. I had good intentions. Giving context would suggest what I mean in this phrase, even if phrase is absolutely nonsense. Probably this comment proves the point.. You can (hopefully) understand what I mean even if its "broken english". Thank you

Comment: @Developer Welcome to ELL! Keep in mind that you shouldn't "intentionally give minimum information out of context." Your question has already been voted to close. Next time such questions will likely be closed by community members. A lot of English learners think if they just give a vague phrase they can get answers that tell them all the possibilities and it would be the best way to get comprehensive answers, but that is simply not true. I understand where you are coming from, but keep in mind: 1. that is not the best way to learn. 2. Vague questions are liable to be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saying that someone has **music in their veins** has two primary meanings:

1. The person is a skilled musician, to the point that musical skill appears to be a part of their biology. Their skill flows like blood in their veins.
2. The person is constantly involved in musical activities. Just as blood is always flowing in their veins, musical topics are always flowing through their mind.

Additionally, the phrase might be used when a person's heritage is associated with an activity. The children of [Neil Armstrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_Armstrong) have **spaceflight in their veins** due to their relationship with their father who is famous for his career as an astronaut. This meaning is usually reserved for cases where the children choose to follow in their ancestral footsteps and pursue the same activities.

This phrase can be used with most nouns, but is most effective with activities.

> She was a gifted judge; she had **the law** in her veins.

> The two-time gold medalist had **cycling** in his veins.

It is not correct to say that someone had **musician** in their veins. The only exception I am aware of is if you are referring to a specific musician in an [appeal to authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority). Here, the skill of a guitarist is compared to that of Jimi Hendrix who is renowned for his mastery of the stringed instrument. The person need not be related to Hendrix.

> He was a skilled guitarist; he had [**Hendrix**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimi_Hendrix) in his veins.

Comment: I always tell people if I down vote. I have downvoted because you are not answering the question. You are guessing what the OP 'probably' means and answering that instead. We need to ask the OP to give all the necessary context. Otherwise we may guess wrongly.  It's happened many times in my experience on this site.

Comment: Thank you @DM. Your answer is exactly what i had in mind. _**"The person is a skilled musician, to the point that musical skill appears to be a part of their biology. Their skill flows like blood in their veins."**_

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica - I don't always tell, but I will this time.